# How to set conditional breakpoint to modify ZF (Zero flag)

Tags: ida, idapython, idc

In IDA I need to set a breakpoint that once it hit, I want to check if `ZF` is equal to 1, if it does, I want to change it to 0.

I don't know how to do it:
[image]

I searched for example scripts in IDC or IDAPython but I didn't find something that shows it.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shift + f2

```
Message("zf flag when bp hit = %x\n" , GetRegValue("zf"));
SetRegValue(0,"zf");
Message("zf flag after setting it %x\n" , GetRegValue("zf"));
```

result

```
zf flag when bp hit = 1
zf flag after setting it 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your case the final value of ZF will be zero, there is no need to check the initial value but simply always zero it:

```
ZF=0,0
```

The `,0` at the end will ensure that the result of expression is 0 so IDA will continue execution of the program.